# working with XML on Android

Tags: android, xml, dom

I m new to Android (porting iOS/Objective C app ) and I have to read an XML (with some nodes in JSON) file returned by a WebService

the response looks like that:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:TPLoginResponse><TPLoginResult>[{"content": "some json content...."]</TPLoginResult></ns1:TPLoginResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

how can I simply get the content of TPLoginResult ?

I tried :

```
            httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object response = envelope.getResponse();

            SoapObject SoapResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;

            Log.e("Info",  "response : " + SoapResponse.toString() ); // content is successfully received here 

            String SResponse =  SoapResponse.toString();

            Log.e("Info",  "DocumentBuilderFactory" );

            // parse the XML as a W3C Document
            DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(SResponse)) );

             NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("TPLoginResult");

             Log.e("info","nList length : " + nList.getLength());
```

but I need a 0 length nList ...

I also tryed :

```
  NodeList nList = document.getElementsByTagName("ns1:TPLoginResponse");
```

but same 0 length result..

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found that it is more easy usign the ksoap methods

```
String LoginResponse = SoapResponse.getProperty(0).toString();
```

Comment: That was what I just suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is in this line:

```
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

if you comment that line you'd be able to get the element with

```
document.getElementsByTagName("TPLoginResponse");
```

otherwise, you'll probably need to use:

```
document.getElementsByTagNameNS(namespaceURI,tag);
```

but i have never used the last line, so i can't help you there.

please let me know how that works for you, i'm interested.

Answer (score 1):

[KSOAP Android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) is a very useful tool to consume SOAP web-services. I use this tool in all my Android applications. And I can say that it works well.

You can find examples in their [wiki](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse) and all over internet.